# List(Of T) tips for performance

Tags: vb.net, performance, list, arraylist, structure

I have been tempted to use List(Of T) in VB.NET instead of ArrayLists by someone-who-must-not-be-named-Robinson.

Essentially, what I need to store are three things: One string, two integers, and maybe two booleans. I liked using ArrayList, because it treated all its elements as "Objects" so I didn't really have problems storing that variety of elements.

But now I have been thinking of using List(Of T). But how do I do to store that variety of elements of mine? I have been thinking on making a `Structure` holding the five elements.

Sounds like a good idea? I heard somewhere that Structures are expected to have a short life. But I fear I will be having my structures for... forever, as long as my application lives. Does that make any difference?

Finally, what if I needed to create... don't know...... 125,000,000 Lists, each containing a structure? Is that possible (and good)?

Comment: Heterogenous collections are usually just a stupid idea, even in dynamic languages. Use a struct (or, perhaps, class) for this. Arrays, ArrayLists, Lists, etc. are all collections that store 0-* instances of the same thing, nothing else. Performance should be your least concern here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a collection type (`ArrayList` or `List(Of T)`) just because you're looking for a place to store a fixed number of completely different types, stop! You're on the right track with creating a structure, though what you're looking for is called a `class`.

Since, from your other questions, it sounds like you're creating a map editor, I'm assuming that your two numbers are X and Y coordinates, and I'd guess the string is a name of some kind? If so, very simple:

```
Public Class Tile 
    Public Property Name as String
    Public Property X as Integer
    Public Property Y as Integer
End Class
```

(Note that the above will only work if you're using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4; if not, respond and I'll edit with a pre-4 compatible version)

It will be much easier for you to refer to the `.X` and `.Y` properties rather than just throwing indexes around all over the place. This will also be *much much* faster (and take up less memory) than doing that.

I'm going to forego a complete description of everything that's there, as descriptions of what a class is and what properties are is pretty readily available. Does that help?

Comment: I have noticed one thing... even if I use a Class for storing my individual tile information, I would still need a huge (I mean, HUGE) 2d array map of Lists for ordering all my Tile classes, no?

Comment: @Omega: Why would you need a 2d array of Lists? It would seem that you'd need a 2d array of Tiles.

Comment: I mean, yeah, a 2d array of Tiles. But I do need Lists to order my Tiles, no? For example: For a 2x2 map, I use two Lists (X coordinate), and two Lists for each X list (Y coordinate), and finally, the Tile is stored in it, right?

Comment: @Omega: I'm not seeing a need for any lists here. The X and Y coordinates are stored as part of the tile and the index locations within your 2D array.

Comment: Oh, I never explained those two integers... they're not the tile's position on the map. They are the position of the 32x32 rectangle where the tileset's bitmap is taken. Let me explain: The string tells the name of the image (a big texture containing all tile graphics), the X and Y are "what part" of such image is used to draw this tile. I was using the 2d lists for locating the tiles.

Comment: @Omega: I would forego the lists and use your 2D array for locating the tiles (using the lists, you're just creating a staggered 2D array anyway, essentially). If you need to, just add two more properties to the class to represent the tile's X and Y. The properties I have above are just examples.

Comment: If a Tile Class represents one tile, I would need.... 250000 instances of such class if the user chose the Max Setting in my map editor. Is that good? Also, since the user can create the map (choose tiles and place them on the map), I would need a way to know "which tile is clicked", how would I find the tile without iterating through the 250000 instances of Tile? Before, I used my two arraylists to locate what tile was clicked..

Comment: @Omega: While that sounds like a lot, 250,000 instances of this simple `Tile` class is preferable to having a similar number of lists. Also, if you're using a 2D array to keep track of the tiles, there's no need to have an actual instance of `Tile` in a given spot if the user hasn't put one there. It can be null (`Nothing` in VB.NET) and you can assign it when they want to put something there. I'm not sure how using the lists made finding the selected tile easier; can you explain?

Comment: When the user clicks the map, the cursor X and Y positions are converted to multiples of 32 (tiles are 32x32), and then, divided by 32. The results are indexes representing the locating of the clicked tile. That's how I located clicked tiles. If I didn't use Lists at all, I would have to iterate through my 250000 instances of class every time a click was done, no?  **Note: Make it 1.25 million instances from now on, is it still good?

Comment: @Omega: If you have a 2D array, you'd just access array[X, Y] to get at the tile. No looping needed.

Comment: I have been making a list inside a list all this time... can you tell me about this "2D array" being accessed by array[X,Y]? Maybe that was my problem all this time =/

Comment: @Omega: I assumed that you knew what it was, since a few comments ago you said a "2d array". A multidimensional array (two-dimensional, in this case) allows you to create an array that has...well...multiple dimensions. For example, I could create a 2D array of `strings` like this: `string[,] myArray = new string[10,20]`. This would give me a two dimensional array, where the first dimension is `10` and the second is `20`. This gives me a total of 200 individual spots, from `myArray[0,0]` to `myArray[9,19]`.